# Delphi TDictionary<String, TDateTime> sort by value

Tags: delphi

I have a `TDictionary<String, TDateTime>` like this

```
aDict := TDictionary<String, TDateTime>.Create;
try
    aDict.Add('Foo', StrToDateTime('2016-10-14 15:00:00'));
    aDict.Add('Bar', StrToDateTime('2016-10-14 14:00:00'));
    aDict.Add('Baz', StrToDateTime('2016-10-14 13:00:00'));
finally
    aDict.Free;
end;
```

if i loop on the dictionary like this:

```
for aKey in aDict.Keys do 
    WriteLn(aKey );
```

the output is:

```
Bar
Baz
Foo
```

The default order seem based on the key alphabetically, i want sort the dictionary from the oldest to the newest TDateTime on the value. the expected output is:

```
Baz
Bar
Foo
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Then TDictionary is the wrong Container.
Create a RecordType for Your List like TmyRecord = record
aname : string aDate : Tdatetime; end;

Use a tList<TmyRecord> and sort like you want

Comment: Thaks... i'm work on TList

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A dictionary is an unordered collection. If it appears ordered in any particular way, that is purely down to chance. The order of the items is not defined in any way.

If you wish to order these items, transfer them to an array (`TArray<string>`) or a list (`TList<string>` or `TStringList`) and order them there.